# ArcGIS Field Maps Inspection Workflows - Join Features layer will not load

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, arcgis-enterprise, arcgis-field-maps, global-id

I'm following the exact workflow described in Part [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0W6X6ovi_Q),  [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqC-EEw3nxY) and [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3iPkATo9R0) of this ESRI video series on YouTube. I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.9 to publish a web layer containing one feature class and one table. There is a 1:M relationship between the feature class Hydrants (GlobalID key) and the table HydrantInspections (GUID key).  Using Map Viewer Classic in an Enterprise 10.9 environment, I'm performing the 'Join Features' analysis to create a new hosted feature layer view "Recent Hydrant Inspections" that shows the most recent inspection data for each hydrant point.  This layer displays correctly in Map View and Map Viewer Classic.

The "Recent Hydrant Inspections" layer will not load in the ArcGIS FieldMaps mobile application (Android or Apple versions).  The error is:

```
Map: Hydrant Inspections Webmap
Layer: Recent_Hydrant_Inspections
Domain: ARCGIS_RUNTIME
Code: 3047
Description: Geodatabase duplicate field not allowed.
```

I believe the issue is that both the feature layer and related table contain a GlobalID field. When I perform Join Features, the resulting layer view contains two GlobalID fields named 'globalid' and 'globalid_1649266887779'.  I can't find any way to remove/rename one of these fields or resolve the issue.

How is it possible to view a 'Join Features' layer view in Field Maps? Why did it work in Eric's demo but not in my environment? I'm wondering if this is a bug in Enterprise but not AGOL that ESRI needs to work out.

UPDATE -  I have been in contact with ESRI about this, and it is now a known bug with Enterprise. They are working on it.